# phonegap + siteminder

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, siteminder

please anyone can help me how to use siteminder in phonegap application? once authuntication from server side(siteminder) then proceed to phonegap application. please with help with some details i am new to Siteminder

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for late update of Answer, i have put an iframe on welcome page of phonegap application. then i hit my server so here comes the siteminder,  my iframe is keep on tracking the home page name onload of ifram. as my username password is approved and reached home page i hit the local home page of my mobile. now my session is created on server and i can communicate with server with no problem

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

SiteMinder is used for authentication purposes and should provide you with a credential once authenticated successfully.  Are you looking to grant permission to proceed to a PhoneGap download which will install the app or are you looking for SiteMinder to be used for each authentication session in order to grant access to a preinstalled PhoneGap app on your device?

Either way you are doing a series of webservice calls to your SiteMinder service from the locally installed PhoneGap app.  Here's the scenario that I envision.

Enter uid
Enter pwd
Submit
credentials submitted to SiteMinder service and validated
If success then Login = True and show app
If failure then Login = False and show Login screen with error message

Comment: i am actually want to achive second scenario.do i need to put the login page of siteMinder in my phone app or i have to recive the renderd page from the server side?