# Siteminder integration with Cordova hybrid app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, siteminder

We have a hybrid mobile application for blackberry 10 build with Phonegap. Our focus is to integrate the application with Siteminder authentication. Once user opens the application. user will be redirected to siteminder authentication screen. can any one tell me how to do it. what are the changes needs to be done from html or js file.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814629/phonegap-siteminder

Comment: Please add more information. What you have done so far, some code, or an example would be helpful.

Comment: Check this for the approach
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078951/cordova-hybrid-app-integration-with-siteminder-protected-rest-resource